# Magento extension setup in admin

Tags: magento

I'm using a Magento Shop Version 1.5.1. 
For invoice payment the extension Mxperts Invoice is installed: https://github.com/sreichel/magento-Mxperts-Invoice/tree/master/app/code/local/Mxperts/Invoice

Right now in the admin form the the invoice: System - Konfiguration (Configuration) - Zahlungsarten (Payment methods) on top of the form there is a strange graphic from http://www.mxperts.de/mxperts.jpg, it seems the site  was maybe hacked.
I try to remove the graphic and all links to this site from the admin form, but I cannot find it anywhere in the code for the extension.

So my question: Where can I find the configuration of this graphic and the link to the site?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code in your module's `system.xml` is responsible for the image and note under that image

As per gitHub url for the module file path will be

> app/code/local/Mxperts/Invoice/etc/system.xml

And Below is the code for the image and note

```
<fields>
    ...
    <note translate="label">
          <label></label>
          <frontend_type>note</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          <comment><![CDATA[
                <a href="http://www.mxperts.de" target="_blank"><IMG border="0" src="http://www.mxperts.de/mxperts.jpg"></a>
                 <div style=""><b>Invoice Payment-Module</b> <a href="http://www.mxperts.de" target="_blank">www.mxperts.de</a></div>
                 <div style="margin-top:4px;"><b>TMEDIA cross communications, <a href="mailto:info@tmedia.de">info@tmedia.de</a></b><br>
                            Johannes Teitge, Daniel Sasse, Igor Jankovic<br></div>
                 <div style="margin-top:4px;"><b>Sponsored by:</b>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.switzerlandshop.com" target="_blank">www.switzerlandshop.com</a></div>
                            ]]>
          </comment>
     </note>
     ....
</fields>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't check that file

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check which module configuration file i.e. check system.xml file.
Try to debug this file.